# Html5 canvas screenshot Blurry

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, canvas, screenshot

I am working on Asp.net application where I have to drag-drop images on A4 size page and then save all these images as single image (collage). I have done almost everything but when I am saving images as single image, final image becomes blurry. I am using html5 canvas for capturing all images as single image. I have tried almost everything but quality of image is still poor. Is there any third party tool or any other alternative of this. Please help.

Below is my code:

```
        var extra_canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = extra_canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, 980, 500);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        window.open(dataURL);
```

Thanks
Tarlok

Comment: What is the size of your original `canvas` ?

Comment: I am guessing you are down sampling, and you should have smoothing on. Your blur is from the low resolution 980 by 580 you are using. Set the canvas size to be as big or bigger than the largest image. After creating canvas and befor get context set `extra_canvas.width(Math.max(img1.width, img2.width, img3.width, canvas.width));` then to keep the same aspect `extra_canvas.height = Math.floor(extraCanvas.width * (500 / 980);` then `ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0,extra_canvas.width,extra_canvas.height)` that should inprove the quality.